# Start activity from notification without createing activity again?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications

I want to start `main.class` activity from notification pending intent
 without start the activity again. I need to open with old details (don't start `onCreate` method).

When i press this notification `main.class` starts but the activity gets created again.
 This is my notification:

```
Context context = Main.this;
Intent i = new Intent(context,Main.class);
PendingIntent pen = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,i,0);
```

How can I open main.class without starting the activity again?
What need to add `onCreate()` or notification?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use " android:launchMode="singleTop"" on androidmanifest file of ur activity.

then,

```
     Context context = Main.this;
     Intent i = new Intent(context,Main.class);
     i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
     PendingIntent pen = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,i,0);
```

Update above on Notification class that will call  oncreate() if ur mainclass not exist otherwise  that will call onNewIntent().

u can create onNewIntent() in mainclass like,

```
   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (getIntent() != null) {
           // do the stuff here.

            }
           }
```

Comment: i use this flags activity start but my service stop then appliction froce stop flags dont work and main.class is not launcher activity

Comment: try this  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
     intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

Comment: instead of  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate method, have a flag which tells you whether this activity was called from another activity or from a service and process accordingly.

When a pending intent starts, it usually starts with the intent's activity's onCreate only.